# Compose: Showing fixed size Box in Annotated String

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a fixed size box of size `17dp*17dp` inside an `AnnotatedString` in `compose`. So, I am appending it as `InlineContent`.

```
inlineContent[id] = InlineTextContent(
        Placeholder(
            width = 17F.dpToSp(LocalContext.current).sp,
            height = 17F.dpToSp(LocalContext.current).sp,
            placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextCenter
        )
    )

fun Float.dpToSp(context: Context): Float {
    val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.scaledDensity
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        this,
        context.resources.displayMetrics
    ) / density
}
```

However, I am observing that the size of the box inside the `AnnotatedString` is less than when I show my `Box` elsewhere(say inside a menu).

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .width(17.dp)
            .height(17.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            .background(color = bgColor),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        Text(
            text = sourceViewId,
            fontSize = 13.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
            color = textColor,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        )
    }
```

I also observed `dpToSp` conversion factor is always 1 on my device i.e. I am getting the same output as input. Android seems to not render `dp` to `sp` conversion correctly. Is there any way to show a fixed `dp` size Box inside a `PlaceHolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Box` inside of the `AnnotatedString` is limited by the size of the `Placeholder` and it will appear smaller because of the `padding`. So you'll have to account for `padding` when deciding on `Placeholder` size.

Also, you can convert `dp` to `sp` in a more succinct way:

```
fun Float.dpToSp(density: Density) = density.run { dp.toSp() }

width = 17f.dpToSp(LocalDensity.current)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, If I don't know the width and height of the Placeholder in advance, can I set its size as required by its content?

Comment: @VivekMangal That depends on how do you get content's size. It would be problematic for a composable inside a Placeholder to find its own size, but might be possible with a custom layout, not sure.